# Visit of Greek philosophers to Rome in 155 BCE

Tags: ancient-rome, ancient-greece, philosophy, sources, hellenistic-greece

In 155 BCE a delegation of three Greek philosophers arrived in Rome on a political mission (to negotiate the settlement of war fines). During their stay they succeeded in raising Greek philosophy to prominent attention and seeding its future important role in Rome. This is one summary (from [SEP](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/stoicism/)):

> In 155 BCE Athens sent a delegation of three philosophers (Stoic,
>   Academic skeptic, and Peripatetic) on an embassy to Rome. Their
>   teachings caused a sensation among the educated. The Skeptic [Carneades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carneades)
>   addressed a crowd of thousands on one day and argued that justice was
>   a genuine good in its own right. The next day he argued against the
>   proposition that it was in an agent's interest to be just in terms
>   every bit as convincing.

Is there a canonical primary source (or recommended secondary source) that covers this significant event in the history of ideas in detail?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for sources.

Comment: @TylerDurden Why is there a tag "sources" in your opinion?

Comment: Questions about primary sources are asking "How do we know this" and are consistently considered on-topic in Meta. They're very different than questions asking for the Top 5 books on the fall of Rome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an explicit request for resources

Answer (score 4):

The three Greek philosophers were:

> [Carneades ex Academia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carneades) (Cyrene  214/3–129/8 BC), [Critolaus Peripateticus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critolaus) (Phaselis c.200-c.118 BC) and [Diogenes Stoicus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogenes_of_Babylon) (Seleucia c.230 – c. 150/140 BC).

Some sources are listed in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critolaus#cite_note-2):

> [Plutarch, Cato Maj. 22](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Plutarch/Lives/Cato_Major*.html); Aulus Gellius, VII. 14; [Macrobius Saturnalia i. 5](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/L/Roman/Texts/Macrobius/Saturnalia/1*.html#5); [Cicero, de Orat. ii. 37, 38](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/oratore2.shtml).